# How to pass the model information to a user control view model that is in a main window?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-toolkit

I'm trying to learn MVVM Pattern doing a simple GUI using WPF . It's just a simple plugin for [Autocad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD) with a modal window showing some information about the model.

I have two Usercontrols with their respective views and viewmodels. I'm showing these usercontrols in a single windows/dialog. One of these usercontrols needs to show some information, representing a simple List (the model) in a DataGrid.

Like I said before, the model for that user control is a existing List. I need to pass the List information to the viewmodel but I'm struggling with this. I was thinking on passing it as a parameter to the MainWindow contructor and then to the respective viewmodel but doesn't sound like a good idea.

What options do I have in this case?

I'm using MVVM Toolkit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `WeakReferenceMessenger`/`StrongReferenceMessenger` to send a message from one view model to another:

```
// Create a message
public class LoggedInUserChangedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<User>
{
    public LoggedInUserChangedMessage(User user) : base(user)
    {
    }
}

// Register a message in some module
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<LoggedInUserChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
    // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
    // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
});

// Send a message from some other module
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new LoggedInUserChangedMessage(user));
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information.